# Superscript price decimal numbers when using Standard Numeric Format Strings

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, string-formatting

I'm using Standard Numeric Format Strings (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#FFormatString)) to format pricing on my page:

```
Dim price As Integer = 378
Dim s As String = (CDec(price) / 100).ToString("F")
```

results in string "3,78" which I print in HTML.

However, I want the decimal part "78" to be superscripted using HTML/CSS. How can I do so?

Comment: Put the part after the comma in a <span> and give that a style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the text is automatically HTML encoded (and you have access to the source of all this) you can use the `<sup>` tag.

To superscript only the `78` part just split the string by `,` (or `.` if that is the case) into an array and join it together again with the tag included.

For example:

```
Dim Parts() As String = s.Split(If(s.Contains("."), ".", ","))
Dim s2 As String = Parts(0) & ",<sup>" & Parts(1) & "</sup>"
```

Comment: @Flo : Whoops. Yes, I meant to use `Parts(0)` and not `s(0)`. ;)